# Is it possible to automate syncing of an external git repo to a AzureDevOps hosted internal git repo?

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to have a AzureDevOps internal git repository that is a forked version of an external open source library. Is it possible for AzureDevOps to have some way of automatically syncing with the external repo everyday?

I guess if it's not possible, I can have a script that automatically pulls from external and pushes to internal repo everyday.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sync repo in bitbucket to Visual studio team service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874462/how-to-sync-repo-in-bitbucket-to-visual-studio-team-service)

Answer (score 0):

If this is hosted on Github you can fork it and then trigger Azure DevOps pipeline on this fork change.