# How to setup permanent sync from Azure DevOps to Bitbucket

Tags: git, azure-devops, bitbucket

I need to sync our Azure DevOps repo to Bitbucket repo. Syncing should be permanent, so that when I push code on Azure DevOps, it updates the code on Bitbucket. The process has to work only from Azure DevOps to Bitbucket, not from Bitbucket to Azure DevOps.

How should I do this?

I have seen solutions for this problem ([How to sync repo in bitbucket to Visual studio team service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874462/how-to-sync-repo-in-bitbucket-to-visual-studio-team-service)), but Azure's UI has changed a lot in a short time, and I can't use those.